# error: failed to import to kibana dashhboards

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
Exiting: Error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to import the dashboards in Kibana: Error importing directory /usr/share/metricbeat/kibana: failed to import Kibana index pattern: 1 error: error loading index pattern: returned 200 to import file: 1 error: error: unknown, asset ID=metricbeat-*; asset type=index-pattern; references=[]. Response: {"successCount":0,"success":false,"warnings":[],"errors":[{"id":"metricbeat-*","type":"index-pattern","title":"metricbeat-*","meta":{"title":"metricbeat-*","icon":"indexPatternApp"},"error":{"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Unexpected bulk response [429] cluster_block_exception: index [.kibana_7.15.2_001] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];","statusCode":500,"type":"unknown"},"overwrite":true}]}
```

Exiting: Error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to import the dashboards in Kibana: Error importing directory /usr/share/metricbeat/kibana: failed to import Kibana index pattern: 1 error: error loading index pattern: returned 200 to import file: 1 error: error: unknown, asset ID=metricbeat-*; asset type=index-pattern; references=[]. Response: {"successCount":0,"success":false,"warnings":[],"errors":[{"id":"metricbeat-*","type":"index-pattern","title":"metricbeat-*","meta":{"title":"metricbeat-*","icon":"indexPatternApp"},"error":{"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Unexpected bulk response [429] cluster_block_exception: index [.kibana_7.15.2_001] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];","statusCode":500,"type":"unknown"},"overwrite":true}]}

Answer (score 0):

your Elasticsearch node is out of disk space, which is what `disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block` is telling you

you will need to figure out what's happened there, either add more space for it or delete data you don't need (using the Elasticsearch API). once you have that sorted, you will need to change the index from read only

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/fix-common-cluster-issues.html#_error_disk_usage_exceeded_flood_stage_watermark_index_has_read_only_allow_delete_block has some good tips here as well